# How do you add the Navigation Tab at once for all the User Interface Views, and not individually for every page?

Tags: iphone, tabs, navigation

Does anybody know how to add the navigation Tab or the ads tabs (AdMob or iAd) in order to be present in an app the whole time, instead of adding them individually to every single page? Basically, to stay at the bottom of the screen the whole time, instead of opening every single xib. file?

I just watched a tutorial on how to add it for start, which is easy, but if I have an app with 1,000 pages, what's a faster version to lock them at the bottom of all pages?

Thanks and sorry for the English, is my second language.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "pages", i think you mean views. If that is the case, then the easiest way to do this is have a view controller that controls the iAds and all your views. That way your iAd is always showing it the parent viewController, and every "page" is showing in the parent view controller as well. This puts the iAd at a global scale rather than a child scale (like you described).